# Eclipse Kepler vs. Package Solutions

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to download Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), but I'm confused as to what the difference is between Eclipse Kepler and the Package Solutions. Are the package solutions merely add-ons? The Package Solution for Java developers includes an IDE, but doesn't Kepler already have an IDE?

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplerr

Comment: "Eclipse Standard" is just another package - each includes various different components.  If you're a Java developer, the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" is probably what you want!

Comment: I see, that makes a bit more sense. Thanks!

Comment: You can find out more about the differences between packages using http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=kepler